# Cakephp how to handle when some X don't belongsTo Y

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a table of 'units', which belongsTo 'Complex'.  But some units are actually houses, which don't have a complex associated with them.  I haven't had any problems until now when trying to display images, because units all display their UnitsImage and their ComplexImage.  Any houses display an error that ComplexImage not defined (obviously).  Is there a way to fix the association or do I need to have another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of the information you have provided I don't believe any changes need to be made within the model. I assume the issue is that in the view you assume an image exists. Have you tried place using an if statement in the view?

```
if($house['House']['Complex']['image']){
  echo $this->Html->image($house['House']['Complex']['image']);
}
```

perhaps you could share the code from your view?

Comment: You know, that is a good idea.  I've done it on other views, why not here?  Derp derp!  I'll post back once I implement and let you know how it goes.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!